# Prolog inheritance rule

Tags: prolog

To determine the animal is bulldog, I have the following predicates:

```
bulldog(X):-
    body(X,muscular),
    weight(X,heavy),
    face(X,wrinkled),
    nose(X,pushed-in).
```

If I had a dog, call him "fifi", and the following facts:

```
body(fifi,muscular).
weight(fifi,heavy).
face(fifi,wrinkled).
nose(fifi,pushed-in).
```

When I enter the following statement:

```
bulldog(fifi).
```

it will return true.

Lets now say I had another bulldog "fofo" and following predicate:

```
bulldog(fofo).
```

When I ask something like

```
body(fofo,muscular). / weight(fofo,heavy).
```

then it will return false. What can I do to let Prolog recognize the characteristic of the bulldog, and return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add extra facts about `fofo` to the knowledge base. Prolog makes a [closed-world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_world_assumption), meaning anything not provable from the facts/rules listed in the program is simply false.

Answer (score 1):

what you wrote is that something is a bulldog IF it's muscular, heavy, wrinkled and pushed-in but no that if something is a bulldog then it would be muscular, heavy, wrinkled in pushed-in.

to do that you could write:

```
body(X,muscular):-
   bulldog(X).
```

etc...

However, if you have:

```
body(X,muscular):-
   bulldog(X).

bulldog(X):-
  body(X,muscular),
  ....
```

you will get stuck in a infinite loop.
you could solve it by using different predicate names:

```
body(X,muscular):-
   bulldog(X).

is_bulldog(X):-
  body(X,muscular),
  ....
```

or somehow detect the loop and stop it (some prolog versions like XSB support tabling)